Replace $\vert1\rangle$ with identity operator
I am learning quantum computing recently and found an exercise on the Internet. I have been thinking about how to solve it but still confused. The following is the question
Consider a single qubit channel which accomplishes the following operation:

With probability $ p = \frac{1}{2} $, it applies an $ X $ gate to the qubit.

With probability $p= \frac{1}{2} $, it performs a measurement in the  $Z $-basis.

If the outcome of the measurement is $+1$ , it replaces the qubit with $ \vert0\rangle $.

If the outcome is -1 , it replaces the qubit with $\frac{1}{2}\Bbb I$.




Find a set of Kraus operators describing this channel.
I think it's easy to find the kraus operator for $X$ gate and for measurement result +1 case. But I am having a hard time figuring out how to replace the state with identity operator, since we know for sure with -1 as measurement, the state is $\vert1\rangle$. Any one have an idea about the case where we get outcome -1 when measuring in $Z$ basis?

Be careful, kets and operators don't live in the same space. You should be working with density matrices instead.

yes indeed. I think I need to find the kraus op which transform |1><1| to Identity/2, but I am having hard time finding such kraus operator.

It requires more than one Kraus operator.
